# Asks for password after first try to SSH to my EC2 AWS Box

Tags: amazon-web-services

Fist time using AWS Instances.  Here's what I did:

1. Created a new EC2 instance
2. Downloaded the key.pem
3. Later decided to delete the key on my instance from the dashboard and create a new key
4. downloaded the new key.pem and replaced the local with that new one
5. Now tried to ssh into it for the first time but I get a password prompt

It's asking for a password, but I have no idea what it is

```
sudo ssh -i my.pem ubuntu@54-86-186-87
```

Trying to ssh from OS X

[image]

I thought since I'm using a key (.pem) I shouldn't need to worry about any password?

**During further troubleshooting**:

when I run `ec2-get-console-output instance_id`, it shows that my instance is under the `ubuntu` user and the `ssh-rsa` fingerprint that shows up in the results of running that command is different for my key name (`Authorized keys from /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys for user ubuntu`).. in fact it shows as even shorter than the fingerprint showing up in my instance in the AWS Dashboard for my instance.

Shouldn't that ssh-rsa key be the same as what's showing for my instance in the AWS Control panel for my instance and match my local private .pem?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not asking a password for SSH, but for `sudo`.

If you're pem file is available to you as user, you don't need to become root to SSH to your EC2 instance.

So just do

```
ssh -i my.pem ubuntu@54-86-186-87
```

If you want to become root on the instance, do `sudo -i` once you're on the box.

---

The user `ubuntu` is the default user for an Ubuntu EC2 instance. If you're unsure which distro is running on your system, do

```
ssh -i my.pem root@54-86-186-87
```

You will **not** login as root, but the instance will tell you what is the default user:

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```

Comment: what do you mean by become root?

Comment: The user `root` is the super user on a linux system. With `sudo` you run a command as the user `root`. With `sudo -i` start a command line shell as root. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Answer (score 0):

When you create an AWS EC2 instance, you specify a PEM key to use with it (at least for Linux instances). That's the only key associated with than instance. If you change the key on your dashboard that doesn't have any effect upon the key already on the instance.

So, the password prompt is because your new key does not match the old key that it is using. If you didn't set up a password or keep the old key, it's essentially impossible to log into your instance.

(It you want to use a new key, you need to add it to all the old instances using the old key first.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect to my instance via Putty and had the same problem... there was a problem with the password and I didn't manage to connect.
My solution:

1. click on your instance id in the instances dashboard.
2. click connect on the top right.
3. click connect on the bottom right (orange button).
4. on the new page that opened write:  sudo passwd ubuntu
5. change the password.
6. go back to your Putty and try to connect with the new password.

It worked for me and hopefully for you too.